# Can I use a 1.25 Amp doorbell with 22 gauge wire?

Tags: electrical

I have 22ga doorbell wire from a doorbell transformer to my doorbell and chime. I have recently bought this [doorbell chime](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KG27K4W), along with this 16V 30VA [doorbell transformer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HKQ4GC3).

I plan to use this with a Ubiquiti g4 pro doorbell rated for 16-24V AC @ 1.25A. Is this okay? I've seen several places on the internet tell me 22ga wire is good to 8A and others say its only good to .75A. I don't want to have any issues with temperature/fire.

Re-posting this as the related posts show discrepancy. Fiasco Labs notes there is a limit of 600mA, however, the other post links https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html which shows 5A should be okay.